How to sync Pycharm and Gitlab across multiple machines
big disclaimer: I'm a noob. I'm just getting started in the world of version control systems.
This is what I would like to achieve:
2 pcs in 2 different places that can work on the same projects, through gitlab, both able to get the full project list through the [get from version control > gitlab] dialog.
This is what my current setup looks like:

I have pycharm 2024.1 on both machines
sync is ON for both versions of pycharm (Settings > Settings Sync)
One machine is running on win11, the other on win10 (can't upgrade, too old)
All projects correctly pushed into the gitlab online repository
Activated login with gitlab token on both machines

This is what I'm getting:
-on the original machine where I usually work (win10) everything is smooth, I can push projects, clone projects, no issues at all.
-on the new machine (win11) when I try to clone a project through the "get from VCS" button, on the gitlab section the project list is always empty. The only way I have to clone a project is to manually enter the repository url
I tried to delete and recreate tokens, change settings, reinstalling git, but seems all to no avail. I'm sure that in my noobishness I missed some critical step, however I can't figure out which one.
Any help on this would be highly appreciated.
